# Can I use Transactions and batched writes for read only?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can I read multi data from firestore in one connection similar to [Transactions and batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) but without written.

For example :

I logged in via google button and player name is Player1

First connection : I want read highest 10 players they have diamonds.

Second connection : I want read diamonds Player1.

Can I mix first and second connection in one connection.

Because I want if first connection failed so cancel second connection. Or if first connection connected successfully and second connection failed so cancel first connection etc... , I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions and batched writes are write operations. There's nothing similar for read operations, nor should it really be needed.

If you want to fail subsequent reads, you should:

- Sequentially start each read, after the previous read has completed.
- Start all reads at the same time, but check the status of each completed read operation. Only continue once all read operations completed successfully.

From reading your question it sound like you want to do a client-side join of the player info for the top 10 ranked players. This typically leads to 11 reads.

- The query to get the top 10 scores, which includes the player's UIDs.
- The 10 individual document reads to get each top player's profile.

In this case you could for example keep a counter to track how many of the player profiles you've already successfully read. Once that counter reaches 10, you know you have all the player profiles, and can start any subsequent operation you might have. If you want to fail the entire operation once any player profile fails to load, you'll want a separate flag for that too.

Comment: Can I use `Transactions and batched` for check if document found in Firestore , if was found so do something but if was not found so cancel connection.

Comment: Don't write any code but tell me if I can or not and If I can do that so I'll try find way by myself.

Comment: Yes, you can read a document in a transaction, and thus check if it exists. But not in a batched write, as that's what sets it apart from a transaction.

Comment: I appreciate your help.